# Is CL_DEVICE_MAX_WORK_ITEM_DIMENSIONS always three?

Tags: opencl

The description is:

> Return type: cl_uint
>
> Maximum dimensions that specify the global and local work-item IDs
>   used by the data parallel execution model. (Refer to
>   clEnqueueNDRangeKernel). The minimum value is 3.

The description for work_dim in clEnqueueNDRangeKernel is:

> work_dim: The number of dimensions used to specify the global
>   work-items and work-items in the work-group. work_dim must be greater
>   than zero and less than or equal to three.

So if work_dim can never be greater than three the maximum dimensions will never be greater than three, right?

Comment: Probably a typo. No idea which is correct, so it might be good to refer this as a specification issue to the Khronos group.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most probably it's a typo in the version 1.0 as suggested by @Simon Richter. And it seems it was corrected. Note that starting the [version 1.1](http://www.khronos.org/registry/cl/sdk/1.1/docs/man/xhtml/clEnqueueNDRangeKernel.html) the explanation given for work_dim is:

> The number of dimensions used to specify the global work-items and work-items in the work-group. work_dim must be greater than zero and less than or equal to CL_DEVICE_MAX_WORK_ITEM_DIMENSIONS.

Comment: I didn't even realize I was looking at 1.0. ...just noticed.

Comment: I checked it on "GeForce GT 635M", "Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-3632QM CPU @ 2.20GHz" and "Intel(R) HD Graphics IvyBridge M GT2" and CL_DEVICE_MAX_WORK_ITEM_DIMENSIONS for all of those devices happens to be  3. (The last device is Intel HD 4000, the CL_DEVICE_NAME attribute is rather nonspecific.)